# SSL errors from Xamarin application WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: node.js, xamarin, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-run

I started getting reports on July 3rd of SSL issues in my xamarin application. I have issues on both iOS and Android that started on July 3rd.

**Android error:**
`MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Ssl error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/tls_record.c:217`

**iOS error:**
`AppleTlsContext.CheckStatusAndThrow (Mono.AppleTls.SslStatus status, Mono.AppleTls.SslStatus[] acceptable) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unknown Secure Transport error 'RecordOverflow'.`

**Full Stack Trace:**
`` ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) APIMethods.BackupData (System.Boolean showPopup) ``

API's are hosted on google cloud run. Using node.js and Express.

I'm unable to reproduce the problem myself. Seems to be specific to the devices. Mostly Samsung devices for Android and above 16.0 on iOS. I'm wondering if a certificate changed recently. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please post the full error log of this problem?

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT I added the full stack trace for my issue. This is all the logging I have available.